# The Internal Structure of A Nucleon

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, quarks

Just like, in a Bohr model, the atom has a particular structure, what is it like inside of a nucleon? Like, are there particular ways the quarks are arranged, and what about the binding energy that comprises the majority of the mass of the nucleon?

Comment: Hi I hope you get a better picture in the answers but to address your first question, my **basic** personal picture is: Each nucleon has 3 quarks,  called valance quarks. The force between these quarks is carried by gluons and in addition there are virtual quark-antiquark pairs continually being created and then decaying. The neutron has 2 down and one up quark and the proton has 2 up and one down quark. I am open to correction on this so hopefully you will get an answer we both can learn from...regards

Comment: Various related questions: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118782/ http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56005/ http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132378/ http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19886/

Comment: As a tagging matter, nucleon structure spans the boundary of nuclear and particle physics and makes only the most modest of contribution to atomic physics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an intuitive picture of the motion of nucleons?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35724/)

Comment: The question that @Mobin suggests is clearly not a duplicate. This question concerns the distribution and behavior of partons *within* a single nucleon, not of nucleons within a nucleus.

Comment: No; I'm asking the structure of the inside of a proton, actually, the  STRUCTURE in NUCLEONS

Comment: Plus, I clearly stated in the text- how are quarks arranged?

Comment: So therefore, I know what's inside of a proton- quarks and gluons